# Errors occurred during the build

Tags: android, import, build, workspace

When I import existing android project in eclipse. I get this error

Building workspace error. Build project has encountered problem.

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android Pre
>   Compiler' on project 'ItemListActivity'. Could not initialize class
>   com.android.xml.AndroidXPathFactory

I try cleaning it, but gets same error at that time too. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with the same "Could not initialize class com.android.xml.AndroidXPathFactory".
The solution I've found was to update my jdk. after that everything was back to normal.